# About Measurable Function

Tags: measure-theory

Is the function $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ defined by 
$$f(x)= \begin{cases} 
-1, &\text{if $x$ is rational}\\
 1, &\text{if x is irrational}\\
\end{cases}$$
is Borel measurable?

Can you give some examples function which is not measurable?

Thank you.

Comment: Please show your working so far :)

Answer (score 2):

A very simple  one. We know there exists a non-measurable set, say $A$. Put $f(x) = \chi_{A \ } - \chi_{A^c} $. Hence, $f$ is non-measurable. Notice, however that $f^2 = 1 $ is measurable.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is measurable since the inverse image of $1$ is set of all irrationals which is $G_\delta$ and the inverse image of $-1$ is set of rationals which is $F_\sigma$. So it is measurable.

An example of non measurable function:
The Cantor-Lebesgue function takes $C$ to $[0,1]$. It is one one and onto. Now consider it's inverse. Now restrict the inverse function only to Non Measurable set on $[0,1]$.  So its range is a subset of Cantor set and hence is measurable. But the inverse image of it is a non measurable function.

Answer (score 0):

The classic example of a non measurable function generally tends to go via the axiom of choice: (This shows the existence of a non measurable set technically, and then just goes "its indicator function isn't measurable")

Let $\mathbb{Q}$ act on $[0,1]$ by addition. Pick a number $x$ in each induced orbit, and consider the set $X$ of these (note that this set is uncountable).

Consider the indicator function $1_X$. This isn't measurable, as the values $1$ are taken on a set $X$ which is non measurable, to see this try and take its measure. Well $\mu(\cup (X+q))=\mu([0,1]) = 1$, where we take the union over all $q\in \mathbb{Q}$ is $\mathbb{R}$. But, this union is disjoint, and the lesbesgue measure is translation invariant, so we would (in fact) have $\sum \mu(X) = 1$, where this sum is infinite, which is a contradiction.